# Why the control goes in "else" part?

Tags: c

```
int a = 8;

if (a==8)
    printf("x");
else 
    printf("y");
```

Though `a` is equal to `8`, it outputs `y`.

Comment: Is this all the code you have in `main`?

Comment: [It does?](http://codepad.org/YTJo2JWg)

Comment: The code above always prints `x`. If your code prints something else, then you omitted vital information in your question.

Comment: He must've designed his own compiler and all hell broke loose.

Comment: Try recompiling your code ("clean-compile"). Sometimes that can fix weird bugs like the one you described.

Comment: What would a C preprocessor macro look like that makes "int a = 8" compile and "if( a == 8 )" fail?

Comment: @AaronDigulla, `#define a *a` could do the trick, I think.

Answer (score 5):

The code above always prints `x`. If your code prints something else, then you omitted vital information in your question.

To find out what that might be, try this:

1. Insert `#undef a` before the `int a = 8;` to make sure there isn't a C preprocessor macro that messes with the code.
2. Swap the condition to see if `a` is really what you expect:

   ```
   if( 8 == a )
   ```

   This little trick also prevents you from the accidental assignment bug (`if( a = 8 )`)

Comment: should also #undef if, else and printf just to be safe...

Comment: @TomTanner ah ah, very bright #define printf(a) fprintf(stdout,"y") or #define if(x) while(0) and #define else

Comment: point 2: if he had done that (accidental assignment), it'd take the 'then' path which he claims isn't happening. if (a != 8) might be a more useful check.

Comment: I know you all owe me a big apology, actually its float rather int.

Comment: :-/ For a simple constant like `8`, this shouldn't matter.